# Warning: returning reference to temporary (from a const)

Tags: c++, temporary

Good morning: the situation is as follows

.h file

```
extern const std::string void_string_;
extern const int zero_int;

template <typename Class>    
inline const Class& zero() 
{
   // an error message
}

template <>
inline const int& zero<int>()
{
    return zero_int;
}

template <>
inline const std::string& zero<std::string>()
{
    return void_string_;
}
```

.cpp file

```
const std::string void_string_="";
const int zero_int=0;
```

Then I call this two functions using

```
zero<int>()
zero<string>()
```

Now, the compiler give me a warning for

```
zero<int>()
Warning: returning reference to temporary
```

Ok, I know, in theory, why I get that warning: when I use a reference to a temporary. That's fine. 
Still I don't get why the *const int zero_int;* is considered temporary.

Thanks for any clarification.

**Edit**: as suggested in a comment, I edited the *Class& zero* template. While initially I couldn't include the error code (because the error message is a function), I cleaned it to post it here and effectively in the process I understood the reason of the error.
Specifically:

```
template <typename Class>    
inline const Class& zero() 
{
    std::cout << "No!" << std::endl; // substitutes the original error message
    return zero_int;
}
```

The error happens when in a line of the code, I call

```
zero<long long int>()
```

which, effectively, creates a temporary. Trying:

```
template <typename Class>    
inline const Class& zero() 
{
    std::cout << "No!" << std::endl; // substitutes the original error message
    return (Class&)zero_int;
}
```

removes the warning, but obviously gives another 'little' problem (namely: the result is not 0, but some random number, probably related to the other bytes the program reads)

At this point the only change I did was to leave Class& zero() undefined.

```
template <typename Class>    
inline const Class& zero(); // left undefined by purpose
```

In this way a get a full error, like:

```
undefined reference to `long long const& zero<long long>()'
```

which will remind me when I have to define the correct specialization.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Your .cpp file must include .h file. With proper includes this code does not generate that warning.

Comment: tested with clang 8: no warning. Of course.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d29bd41b1d5197).

Comment: Also [cannot reproduce with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/367b82aad941d228)

Comment: There was a comment pointing out the problem was probably in inline const Class& zero() 
{
   // an error message
}
He was right. I am going to edit the original question and adding an example of code. 
My raw guess is that the problem is that, when I use zero<long long int> (one of the calls), it creates a temporary